# Does the ordinary differential equation exist?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

Does the solution x=$\phi$(t) of an ordinary differential equation

$f(t)=\frac{dx}{dt}$, where $$ f(t)=\begin{cases}
    1, & \text{for $t{\geqslant}0$}\\
    0, & \text{for t <0}
\end{cases} $$
exists $\forall$ t $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$

My answer is yes. If I take a piecewise solution defined here such as -$t^{3}$ for $t<0$ and $t^{3}$ for $t\geqslant$0  . In both cases the result is 0 however I'm not sure if I'm thinking about this problem correctly. Am i allowed to assume an arbitrary solution and conclude a result? Or do I have to use x=$\phi$(t) ?$$
$$I was given the solution here and asked if it exists which is where my confusion is. I'm accustomed to doing the reverse in which i was given the pdf and then solved. What is the methodology behind approaching this questions?

Comment: You can simply integrate this up to get $$x(t)=\begin{cases}t+\alpha&t\ge 0\\\alpha&t<0\end{cases}$$What do you mean by these $t^3$'s? They do not solve the given equation. If you can come up with a solution to a first order differential equation, and it has 1 degree of freedom (i.e. an arbitrary constant somehow involved), then yes, you can conclude that this _is_ the general solution to the differential equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply solve the equation separately for $t \geq 0$ and $t < 0$. In other words you have to solve the equations
$$1 = \dfrac{dx}{dt} \quad \text{ and }  \quad 0=\dfrac{dx}{dt}.$$

Comment: I see now.. Thanks for the clarification.